# Code-Highlighting of CSS Selectors in Strings

Tags: css, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

As the title suggests I would like to know how WebStorm (or any other editor) determines whethere a string is a CSS selector.

[image]

As seen in this image, WebStorm is aware that the string passed to `document.querySelector` is a CSS selector and highlights it accordingly.

My own function on the otherhand does not benefit from this.

The type of `selectors` is `string` for both my method and `querySelector`. Is this just hard coded into the editor or do I have any way of telling it that the argument should be treated as a CSS selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain patterns are known to the editor (hardcoded) - `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, `$` (JQuery), etc. - CSS is auto-injected in such calls.

For your own functions, you need injecting the language manually using [injection comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments), for example:

```
// language=JQuery-CSS
scrollToTop('#id')
```

or create a [permanent injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/using-language-injections.html#configure-injection-rules) with the following *Places pattern*:
`+jsLiteralExpression(jsArgument(jsReferenceExpression().withQualifiedName("scrollToTop"), 0))` in **Settings | Editor | Language Injections**

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! Unfortunately injection comments can not be added to the declaration of the method so I would have to add it to every calling of the method.